# Does updating objects' field in array in Mongo collection not work in meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I tried to use positional $ operator to update the value of the object's field in the array, and used the example from the Mongo docs (  docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/  ) - but that example did not work in meteor. Does it my error or some restrictions of mongo in meteor? Here is the code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) { 

console.info( "Create collection");
students = new Mongo.Collection('students');
console.info( "Clear collection from old data");
students.remove(); 

//***************************************************
console.info( "Insert data to collection");

if (students.find().count() === 0) {

  students.insert({
    _id: 4,
    grades: [
     { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { grade: 90, mean: 85, std: 3 }
      ]
    });

}

//***************************************************
console.info( "Update data in collection");

// Example from  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/
// Use the positional $ operator to update the value of the std field in the embedded document with the grade of 85:

students.update(
   { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 85 },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
);
console.info( "Update data in array with id 4 in collection - OK");


//***************************************************
console.info( "See updated data");

console.info("New data in the field std must be 6 but = " + students.findOne({_id: "4"}).grades[1].std);}
```

The result is the same old value "5" without any error message. What may be the reason that example from Mongo doc does not work?

Comment: The positional $ operator does work in Meteor, I'm not sure why your code isn't working though yet...

Comment: All start to work when I place quotes everywere:

Comment: All start to work when I place quotes everywere:   `students.update(
   { _id: "4", "grades.grade": "85" },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : "6" } }`   May be it is the Meteor's or JS's special feature :-) ?  I hope it will help to someone else :-)

Comment: any key with the dot separator needs quotes. so while 85 does not need quotes, "grades.grade" does.

Comment: Yes, I know that about quotes for key with the dot separator, but my code had them initially and start to work only when I set quotes for "85" etc. numbers as for strings.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the info you gave in the comments above. You state that the code started working perfectly as soon as you put quotation marks in and ask if this is some special `Meteor` or `JavaScript` feature. The answer is no, it isn't a special feature

The reason you need quotation marks to make the code work is that you are saving your number as `Strings` instead of `Numbers`. You need to refactor your insertion/update code to make sure you are inserting  `85` as a `number` not a string. Then you can remove the quotation marks and the code will work.

You may think there's no need to do this as everything is working as expected but if the numbers are being saved as strings then performing maths on them and querying them using `$gt` or `$lt` later will be affected.

To save the numbers as `numbers` instead of `strings` just make sure there are no quotation marks when you insert/update them. It seems your current code doesn't have quotation marks but your comment states that it did previously. So reset your DB by running `meteor reset`, the insertion script will run and then if you remove the quotation marks you just added the code will run as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I see it is necessary to give more attention to the type of the data (I study both JS and Meteor and Mongo from scratch, so sometimes do so errors :-)